# Properties aren't initialising

Tags: objective-c

No matter what I do I cant seem to initialise any of these properties, I always get 0 or null as an output.

```
Player.h:
@interface Player : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@end

Player.m:
@implementation Player
@synthesize name;
@end



MainGameDisplay.h:
#import "Player.h"
@interface MainGameDisplay : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    Player *player, *rival1, *rival2, *rival3;
}

MainGameDisplay.m:
-(void) initCharAttributes {
    player = [[Player alloc] init];
    player.name = @"PlayerName";
    NSLog(@"NAME:%@", player.name);  //Output=  NAME:(null)
}
```

Comment: What is your target version? Also do you have the latest version of XCode? If so you can get rid of the @synthesize and the backing iVar as they aren't necessary with the latest compiler.

Comment: @Ben M iPhone simulator 6.1

Comment: Go to your Target and look at the Deployment Target field. That's one I'm referring to for your target version. Thanks!

Comment: Try getting rid of the instance variable `name` and `@synthesize name`, as they are both unnecessary since things are now automatically synthesized.

Comment: is the `player` object instantiated correctly? I mean, the pointer is pointing to a valid object?

Comment: @BenM 6.0 is the deployment target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes. You don't need to expose so much of your implementation on MainGameDisplay.h. Also your properties will be autosynthesize so your @synthesize and backing iVar are not necessary. Additionally, you shouldn't start a method name with init unless it is responsible for initializing an instance of your class.

```
Player.h:
@interface Player : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end

Player.m:
@implementation Player

@end



MainGameDisplay.h:
@interface MainGameDisplay : UIViewController

MainGameDisplay.m:
#import "Player.h"

@interface MainGameDisplay () <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@implementation MainGameDisplay {
    Player *player, *rival1, *rival2, *rival3;
}

- (void)charAttributes {
    player = [[Player alloc] init];
    player.name = @"PlayerName";
    NSLog(@"NAME:%@", player.name);  //Output=  NAME:(null)
}
```

Comment: Haven't got the latest version of Xcode so I still need to synthesize. I changed the rest of what you suggested and it still doesn't work though.

Comment: If you are able to build for 6.0 your version of XCode includes autosynthesize. Make sure you are using the Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 (search for compiler on the build settings). Where are you invoking charAttributes?

Comment: Some other method, I've only included the code that has anything to do with name and Player.

Comment: The reason I ask is that if your MainGameDisplay controller hasn't completed it's initialization or been initialized properly the player ivar may not be available.

Comment: Ahh, well I removed @Synthesize and the iVar, still the same problem though.

Comment: I'm really not sure, can you come into iOS/Cocos2D chat?